# создание dll в codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Всем привет. Создаю dll в codeblocks, имею структуру проекта main.cpp и main.h. После того как делаю build на выходе получаю три файла: .dll .a .def. Всю эту красоту подключаю в Qt. Qt, конечно же, просит подключить еще и header, прописываю ему путь до main.h. В итоге все работает, все хорошо. Но include выглядит - #include "main.h", что не очень красиво. Вопрос-можно ли как то поменять название header, например с main.h на myApi.h, или же как то сразу в codeblocks создать структуру не main.cpp main.h, а скажем myApi.cpp maApi.h? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не только моно, но и нуно… Более того, для предотвращения конфликта имен имеет смысл помещать заголовочный файл в папку, соответствующую имени пространства имен, как сделано в boost. Например `#include <my_library/core.h>`

Comment: Это то понятно, что нужно отдельную папку, внутри dll тоже namespace юзать. Но вот как имя хедера другое задать?

Comment: А что, codeblocks не дает выбирать произвольные имена для файлов?

Comment: Нет. Он дает выбрать имена только для файлов .dll .a .def. А файлы .cpp .h  всегда main, без права rename. Ну или просто я не нашел где можно задать имена

Comment: Не может быть. Иначе как же писать библиотеки из множества файлов? А если в project explorer выделить файл и нажать F2? Или При добавлении нового файла указать собственное имя?

Comment: f2 не работает. Кажется разобрался, надо по новой создать два файла .срр .h и назвать их как надо. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: В c::b как то не понятно как переименовать файл в проекте, пользуюсь проводником в виде ФарМенеджера :)